# iptables block access to all ports except from a partial IP address

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm looking to block all ips from my server and it's ports with the exception of a partial ip 198.55.**.***. I'd like to limit access to an ISP region do to the fact my personal ip isn't static with our ISP. How would I go about this? Our server was compromised this evening and I'm trying to kill all other traffic to it.

The code below seems to allow a specific ip, but does it block every other IP? Also if I use the x will that act like a wildcard?

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 74.231.64.xx -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to block all incomming traffic except an specific range, you should first change the default policy of the INPUT chain to DROP:

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
```

Then, you should give a netmask to `iptables` to allow many IP addresses altogether exceptionally. For example, if you need to only allow `74.231.64.1`, `74.231.64.2`, to `74.231.64.255`, you can use following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 74.231.64.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

`74.231.64.0/24` tells to iptables to apply the same role to all varying IPs between `74.231.64.1` to `74.231.64.255`. Similarly, you can widen this range by passing `74.231.0.0/16` or `74.0.0.0/8` instead.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Before applying this change, you better have a direct access to the system, not an over-network access. This is because a miss type may block you from the server.

Comment: Just to be clear, this will continue to allow my ip while disabling all others? Also, what does the 0/8 mean?

Comment: No. This command blocks all IPs within this range, allowing all the other IPs to come in. Give the IP that you want to block instead of `74.231.64.0`. more information is added to the answer.

Comment: I need to block all public ip's from being able to access the server with the exception of mine. The only reason I wanted the last few numbers to be dynamic is only do to the fact my ISP could give me a new ip breaking my own access to the server. would it be easier to only give access to mine rather than trying to block all others?

Comment: Yes. It would be easier. You should change the default policy of INPUT chain to DROP and add an exception for you IP address. The answer is updated again.

Comment: Make sure to accept your specific IP before setting the policy to drop. Otherwise, YOU LOST YOUR SERVER FOREVER!!!